# One Java File, but two classes

Tags: java, compilation

I have in my project a few classes. After compiling I find for two java-Files to classes for each: name.class and name$.class. What can be the reason for that? I see nothing special about the classes.

Greetings

Comment: Please post your class(es) definition.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147099/why-does-java-generate-multiple-class-files-on-compilation

Comment: The compiler will create a class file for every class... Even if there are multiple classes defined in the same .java file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android or Java class naming with $ symbol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203829/android-or-java-class-naming-with-symbol)

Answer (score 7):

It is an anonymous inner class, like on example:

```
new Runnable() { ... }
```

**Edit:** some valid points from the comments:

- `enum` types are also compiled to a separate class files (as these are in fact classes)
- anonymous inner classes are numbered sequentially (`MyClass$1.class`, `MyClass$2.class`, etc.)
- unanymous inner classes are named (ex. `MyClass$InnerNamedClass.class`)

Comment: If you have more than one anonymous inner class they will be called MyClass$, MyClass$1, MyClass$2 etc.

Comment: Thanks for so quicks answers. I have two Threads with run(). So it would explain the two classes.

Answer (score 2):

You have an inner class (anonymous or named) in your public class.  This behavior is normal; the Java compiler will produce one .class file for every class, no matter how many classes are defined in a source file.

Answer (score 0):

Java compile creates a .class file to every class defined on the .java file. You should have a anonymous inner class like this:

```
button.addListener(new PressListener() {
    public void onPressed(Event event) {
        System.out.print("test");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner classes in Java are compiled to `Class$InnerClass`.

If you have named classes then the name of the class is used. If the class in anonymous, i.e. you have something like:

```
final ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
};
```

Then numbers are used, so this would be `Class$1`.